# Variadic template class's constructor fails to accept variable argument

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, c++14, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I am trying to understand how variadic templates work.
In the below example I want to pass variable arguments to the class's constructor and store it to a tuple that I can use later.

```
template<typename... Args>
class CompoundOrs
{
public:
    CompoundOrs(){}

    CompoundOrs(Args... args) {
        m_tuple_args = std::tuple<Args...>(args...);
    }

    virtual bool eventPredicate() {
        return unpack_tuple(m_tuple_args, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>());
    }

    bool iterativeOr(bool evt) {
        return evt;
    }

    bool iterativeOr(bool evt, Args... args) {
        return (evt || iterativeOr(args...));
    }

    template<std::size_t... Is>
    bool unpack_tuple(const std::tuple<Args...>& args, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return iterativeOr(std::get<Is>(args)...);
    }

private:
    std::tuple<Args...> m_tuple_args;
};
int main()
{
    bool a = true;
    bool b = false;
    bool c = true;
    CompoundOrs<bool> c_or(a, b, c);

    return 0;
}
```

This throws a compilation error indicating argument mismatch. I read somewhere that the order of declaration of my base function also matters which is why I added the empty constructor as the first one but that didnt help either.

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:64:33: error: no matching function for call to 'CompoundOrs::CompoundOrs(bool&, bool&, bool&)'
     CompoundOrs<bool> c_or(a,b,c);
                                 ^
main.cpp:28:5: note: candidate: CompoundOrs::CompoundOrs(Args ...) [with Args = {bool}]
     CompoundOrs(Args... args)
     ^
main.cpp:28:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
main.cpp:19:1: note: candidate: CompoundOrs::CompoundOrs() [with Args = {bool}]
 CompoundOrs()
 ^
main.cpp:19:1: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 3 provided
main.cpp:15:7: note: candidate: constexpr CompoundOrs::CompoundOrs(const CompoundOrs&)
 class CompoundOrs
       ^
main.cpp:15:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
main.cpp:15:7: note: candidate: constexpr CompoundOrs::CompoundOrs(CompoundOrs&&)
main.cpp:15:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be simplified to

```
#include <tuple>
template<typename... Args>
class CompoundOrs
{
    private: std::tuple<Args...> m_tuple_args;

    // template constructor accepting another set of arguments
    // and forwarding them to tuple field constructor.
    public: template<typename... InnerArgs>
    CompoundOrs(InnerArgs &&... args) : m_tuple_args{::std::forward<InnerArgs>(args)...} {}
};
int main()
{
    bool a = true;
    bool b = false;
    bool c = true;
    CompoundOrs<bool, bool, bool> c_or(a, b, c);

    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zLC8zxLFKam70Pzm)

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me. What I was missing is specifying the template type during specialization.